# What is the green stuff in the bottles?

Tags: the-evil-within

I recently got The Evil Within and I found a bottle full of green liquid. I call it gel, but a part of me doesn't think thats it. I also recently found out it is used to upgrade abilities and weapons.

Comment: Uhhh... what does the game call it?

Comment: I didn't see a name when I was playing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's referred to as Green Gel.

per the  [wiki](http://theevilwithin.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Gel):

> Green Gel is an item found in The Evil Within. After collecting a
>   certain amount of Green Gel, it is possible for Sebastian Castellanos
>   to **upgrade his abilities**.